# Haskell Task Instance General

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble solving a problem in which I'm supposed to calculate the area.
I don't know exactly how to calculate the area and then implement it in the program.
I looked it up and the area is probably calculated using the formula: A = ½·d1·d2·sin π where d1, d2 are the diagonals, which intersect at the angle π.
But how do I implement this in the program?

My code looks like this:

```
class Poly p where
  area_q :: p -> Float

data Quad = MQuad{
qP1 :: Point,
qP2 :: Point,
qP3 :: Point,
qP4 :: Point}
deriving Show
```

```
**Problem**
instance Poly Quad where
   area_q (Quad (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2) (Point x3 y3) (Point x4 y4)) = ((sqrt(x3-x1)^2*(y3-y1)^2)*(sqrt(x4-x2)^2*(y4-y2)^2)*sin(pi))/2
```

Well, that's how I implemented it, but when I use my examples, the result is 0, although the area is not equal to 0 (for my examples).
Is the formula wrong or did I implement it wrong?

I appreciate the help and explanation, thank you in advance!

Comment: `sin pi` is `0` https://www.google.com/search?q=sin+pi

Comment: @Dogbert They're using π as a variable, not the constant.

Comment: @rogerobi Since π is such an important constant, it's not generally used as a variable. θ is more commonly used as a variable representing an angle.

Comment: @chepner Yes, they're using π as a variable. But they're using `pi` as a constant. (Whoops!)

Comment: Whoops indeed on my part!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write

```
sin(pi)
```

which mimics your formula. But in your description of the formula, you say π is the intersection angle, whereas in the code, `pi` is `3.1415927` completely independently of the shape of the quadrilateral.

Additionally, you write

```
sqrt(x3-x1)^2*(y3-y1)^2
```

which corresponds to the math expression (√(*x*<sub>3</sub> - *x*<sub>1</sub>))<sup>2</sup>(*y*<sub>3</sub> - *y*<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>, but the correct formula for distance is √((*x*<sub>3</sub> - *x*<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (*y*<sub>3</sub> - *y*<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: ok! now I understand it, thank you so much :)